# How to resolve error about unpublished child workflows

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, business-process-management

I am receiving an error with a Business Process that I have set up on a custom entity.

Error message - 'This workflow cannot run because one or more child workflows it uses have not been published or have been deleted. Please check the child workflows and try running this workflow again'.

We have several workflows that run from this process flow, however I cannot find the source of the issue.

What is the best procedure to resolve this error?

Thanks
Joab

Comment: The only procedure is going through the process by hand: do all child workflows invoked by the process exist and are all active ?

Answer (score 0):

Open the business process, look for the start child workflow steps. Click the workflow name to open the child workflow, activate the workflow.

Failing that, go to settings > processes, and change the view selector to draft processes. Activate all the processes.